# Concatenate or TextJoin doesn't work when a column is deleted - what's the fix?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

When I use concatenate or TextJoin in Google sheets, they work perfectly but when I delete one of the columns, the joint column gives a #REF! error.

Is there a fix or work around?

[Here's the link to my Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NRiapQwWEQVrfs1GCzCJZuAGP2aeO8tLfOZEjBLAhw/edit#gid=1322687340)

Answer (score 1):

**Hello Irman,**

The **#REF!** error*(the “ref” stands for reference)* gets displayed when a formula refers to a cell that's not longer valid. This tends to happens most often when cells that were referenced by formulas get deleted, or pasted over. Hence, when erasing any of the columns containing the values being concatenated, you break the reference that this cell had to join both values on adjacent columns.

Best thing to do to avoid this in your case is not to erase the column but instead only erase its values that way you don't break the references, although I don't find any particular reason for deleting something that you are using as reference for another formula, however, that will be my best advice on this matter.

I certainly hope this answers your question, buddy. Cheers!

Please find on the link below some alternatives to fix this error.
[How to correct a #REF! error](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-ref-error-822c8e46-e610-4d02-bf29-ec4b8c5ff4be)

Answer (score 0):

its a standard behaviour but you can try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,A1:A&", "&INDIRECT("B1:B")))
```

[image: 0]